# SQL server query -- multiple row value check for the same request number

Tags: sql, sql-server

please help me to get solve this below scenario.
I am new to the SQL server management

Table

| Request | Obj |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 483 |
| 123 | 456 |
| 456 | 456 |

I have a table like this in the server

I need to get the result as below

| Request | result |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | new |
| 123 | new |
| 456 | WIP |

The logic is
If the request have both 483 and 456 object then this will be "new"
If the request have only 456 and not have 483 then it will be WIP

Can someone please help me to get the code for those requirements

Thank you for your time and help

Code [Resolved]

```
SELECT T.Request,(CASE WHEN (D.cn = 2 AND obj = 483 OR obj = 456) OR (D.cn = 1 AND obj = 456) THEN 'NEW'
                       WHEN (D.cn = 1 AND obj = 483) THEN 'WIP'
                       WHEN (D.cn = 2 AND obj = 256 OR obj = 283) OR (D.cn = 1 AND obj = 283) THEN 'Cancel'
                       WHEN (D.cn = 1 AND obj = 256) THEN 'Cancel - WIP'
                       ELSE 'NA' END) AS [Result]
FROM table_name T
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT Request
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN obj IN (483,456,283,256) THEN obj END) AS cn
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Request
) D
ON T.Request = D.Request
ORDER BY T.Request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that you may have more than two rows for a request value, you may use conditional count on the distinct values of 'Obj' to check if a request has the two values (483, 456), then join this to your table to get the desired output.

```
SELECT T.Request,
           CASE 
             WHEN D.cn = 2
             THEN 'New'
             ELSE 'WIP'
           END AS result
FROM table_name T
JOIN
(
  SELECT Request, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Obj IN (483, 456) THEN Obj END) AS cn
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY Request
) D
ON T.Request = D.Request
ORDER BY T.Request
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fLtSUPZJ).

Comment: Thank you for the inputs

@ahmed we are near to the results, let try with some more data with some other cases as well.

483 AND 456 = "NEW",  
456 = "NEW - WIP",
483 = "NEW", 

283 AND 256 = "Cancel",    
256 = "Cancel - WIP",
283 = "Cancel"

Here are the some other combination of logics

CASE 
             WHEN D.cn = 2
             THEN 'New'
             ELSE 'WIP'
           END AS result
this condition will result all the D.cn if it "1" then it will mark under WIP, But we might have  one obj which should come under "New"

Can you please try with this logic as well

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.Request
,(CASE WHEN (D.cn = 2 AND obj = 483 OR obj = 456) OR (D.cn = 1 AND obj = 456) THEN 'NEW'
WHEN (D.cn = 1 AND obj = 483) THEN 'WIP'
WHEN (D.cn = 2 AND obj = 256 OR obj = 283) OR (D.cn = 1 AND obj = 283) THEN 'Cancel'
WHEN (D.cn = 1 AND obj = 256) THEN 'Cancel - WIP'
ELSE 'NA' END) AS [Result]
FROM table_name T
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT Request
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN obj IN (483,456,283,256) THEN obj END) AS cn
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Request
) D
ON T.Request = D.Request
ORDER BY T.Request
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).